# Model does not seem to be getting saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I am using the devise gem to generate users for my web app. I have a Business model that is a `has_one: association` with my User. When I attempt to create a business when logged into my user it simply does not save it. Also when i use rails console in the terminal attempting to open up my Business model returns nil. In the view that is calling .business on the user shows nothing

**Here is my business model**

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :business, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                                    styles: { medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100x100#", post_pic: "44x44" }, 
                                    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**Business controller**

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_business, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @businesses = Business.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @business = current_user.build_business
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @business = current_user.build_business(business_params)

    if @business.save
      redirect_to @business, notice: 'Business was successfully created.' 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @business.update(business_params)
      redirect_to @business, notice: 'Business was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @business.destroy
    redirect_to businesses_url, notice: 'Business was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_business
      @business = Business.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def business_params
      params.require(:business).permit(:name, :desc, :avatar)
    end
end
```

**VIEW THAT CALLS THE BUSINESS**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                    <%= image_tag current_user.business.avatar.url(:thumb), class:"img-thumbnail" %>
                    <%= current_user.business.name %>
                    <%= current_user.business.desc %>
                    <%= link_to 'create business', new_business_path, class:"pull-right" %>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the errors while saving ? can you check with @business.errors

Comment: thats the thing theres no errors, its just not showing up. Very weird.. Let me add the view that im calling this.

Comment: where is business form view?

Comment: have you installed byebug gem ? if yes then put byebug before @business.save and check what's issue.

Comment: Yes I do, it came preloaded when I created the rails project. How would I go about using it

Comment: check here https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Comment: ok thanks! Also when I went onto the rails console to check for Business.first it returned nil even thou I just created a "new" business. I was wondering what could this mean if you had any suggestions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106424/discussion-between-lhh-and-edward-lim).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `user_id` column in your business table? It would look like this: `t.integer  "user_id"`

Then, to directly associate the business with the user, in `businesses_controller.rb` I would write the new and create methods in that way:

```
  def new
    @business = current_user.businesses.new
  end

  def create
    @business = current_user.businesses.new(business_params)
    if @business.save
      redirect_to @business, notice: 'Business was successfully created.' 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: dont belive that works my type of has_one association. It dosent recognize it